# How to sync a table between oracle and sybase

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sybase, development, dts

I have a table in **Sybase** (destination) that I would like to keep it synced with a table in **Oracle** (source)

I cannot truncate and populate the table in Sybase because it is used by an application, I can only add new records and update changes, changes only happen to one column.

In my environment I have Sybase, Oracle, SQL Server & .net development

Whats the best, simplest & reliable way to get this task done, should I develop a DTS, a .net app, use linked server of SQL Server or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Oracle Data Integrator for this. See [Oracle Data Integrator documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/data-integrator/overview/index.html) for a good starting point. If you want you can build this yourself. [Change Data Capture](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/integrate.1111/e12643/data_capture.htm) can be used. Make a change table in Oracle that receives the change records from the Oracle source and implement the change records to the sybase destination tables.

Comment: we don't have this product and its not free.

Comment: you asked for the best , simplest & reliable way to get this task done. That has a price. Coding for Change Data Capture also has a price, lot's of time to solve bugs.

Comment: That's right @ik_zelf, i want the best way with the tools i have DTS, a .net app or linked server

Comment: I edited my answer a little. You do need Oracle technology like CDC to get the changes. Use any host language to transfer the changes. In the end data integrator might be a better option, if complexity grows.

Comment: thanks, I read the link you posted about CDC, it still requires ODI, and as i mentioned we don't have ODI and no plans to buy it